# Adding query options always result in XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY error

Tags: marklogic

Till now I have tried adding query options via Marklogic Java API and .../config/query/... end-point. Everytime I try to do so, I receive following error: `XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY: xdmp:apply(function() as item()*) -- Cannot apply an update function from a query`. Is there a way to fix this or another approach for adding query options?

Code which I use to add options via Java is following:

```
        QueryOptionsManager qoManager = databaseClient.newServerConfigManager().newQueryOptionsManager();
        String optionsXML =
                """
                            <search:options xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
                                <search:sort-order type="xs:int" direction="ascending">
                                    <search:element ns="" name="organizationTypeForSort"/>
                                </search:sort-order>
                                <search:sort-order type="xs:int" direction="ascending">
                                    <search:element ns="" name="numerationForSort"/>
                                </search:sort-order>
                                <search:sort-order type="xs:int" direction="descending">
                                    <search:element ns="" name="publishYearForSort"/>
                                </search:sort-order>
                                <search:sort-order type="xs:int" direction="ascending">
                                    <search:element ns="" name="additionalElementNumberForSort"/>
                                </search:sort-order>
                            </search:options>
                        """;
        StringHandle options = new StringHandle(optionsXML).withFormat(Format.XML);
        qoManager.writeOptions(SORTING_OPTIONS_NAME, options);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to load those query options? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/query-options#id_83483

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes, I have added the code in the update of my post

Comment: So, is executing this Java code what is resulting in the XDMP-UPDATEFROMQUERY? Or are you now trying to do it some other way and having trouble?

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes, executing this Java code is resulting in this error. And on the other hand, sending those query options via REST API is also resulting in this error, but returned in response body.

Comment: When I execute that code, it saves the options without error or exception. Can you run that in isolation and verify that you are getting the XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY? Also, what version of MarkLogic are you using? I tested against 10.0-9.4

Comment: @MadsHansen Okay, I executed this code against local MarkLogic database and options have been saved successfully (version 10.0-9.2). However I need to save them to non-local instance whose version is 10.0-7.3. I am 100% sure that I get XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY error. Would upgrading version solve the problem? Or maybe there might be some configuration problems with this MarkLogic database?

Comment: Is it possible that the modules DB was changed to the filesystem or a different modules DB on the system that is throwing an error? There are resources installed in the modules DB when making it a REST API appserver, and they have to be available or you can get that confusing error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons why you might get this error is if there have been changes to the REST API appserver that invalidate the configs.

There is a [warning in the documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021):

> Changing the configuration of the Application Server for a REST instance is not advised without expert guidance. REST Server behavior is indeterminate after changes to the Application Server. Do not change the root, port, modules, database, error format, error handler, or rewriter, as these are known to cause the REST instance to fail.

For instance, changing the modules DB to filesystem. If the REST server has “filesystem” as its modules database, calls to POST:/v1/config/query/ result in an error message because MarkLogic Server expects a REST instance to be associated with a modules database, rather than a filesystem, and some of the installed resources are not available.

Another reason for getting this error might be changes to the rewriter that invalidated that endpoint routing and configuration.

Comment: Yes, it happened to be a problem with REST API. Workmates from DevOps took your advices and fixed the problem. Thank you very much for help.